# Error when creating database with a RoR app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, rake

I get this error message when running `rake db:create`

```
Could not find gem 'sqlite3 (>= 0, runtime)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
```

Any ideas on what I should do?

Comment: put gem 'sqlite3' in your gem file and run bundle install.

Comment: how do I put it in my gem file?

Comment: I see the text "gem 'sqlite3'" in the gem file, I ran bundle install and it still didn't work

Comment: are you running rake like this: bundle exec rake db:create ?

Comment: no just `rake db:create` in the directory of the RoR app

Comment: should edit your RoR app's "Gemfile". put "gem 'sqlite3'".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open `Gemfile` from the root of your Rails application
2. Add  this line `gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'`
3. run `bundle install`
4. run `rake db:create`

Answer (score 0):

I'm totally new to Rails development, but I had this same problem this week.  Eventually, I replaced the line `gem 'sqlite-ruby, :require => 'sqlite3'` with `gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.2.5', :require => 'sqlite3'` (in the Gemfile)

I had to do this because I'm running Mac OS 10.5.8 rather than 10.6

Maybe that will help.